# comparison of passing 2d array in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, parameter-passing, multidimensional-array

In C

```
void foo(int size ,int a[][size])
{
    printf("%d\n", a[0][0]);
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a[5][5] = {0};
    foo(5, a);
    return 0;
}
```

works fine

But the same in C++

```
void foo(int size, int a[][size])
{
    cout << a[0][0] << endl;
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a[5][5] = {0};
    foo(5, a);
    return 0;
}
```

doesnt work. It gives two errors:

```
 error: use of parameter ‘size’ outside function body
 In function ‘void foo(...)’:
 error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
```

Can anyone explain why this happens. Please also explain any compiler dependent issues either in C or C++..

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423902/does-c-allow-vlas-as-function-parameter).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ is not a superset of C anymore. You are using the C variable-length array functionality, for which C++ has no equivalent. This is illegal C++ and frankly, it's plain really bad practice. Use `std::array` and a template. That's what they're for. Because C arrays are terrible.

Comment: "C arrays are terrible" - at least in C++ (In C, we would have a hard time writing programs without them). Also, a `const vector<int> &` would do the job pretty well too, and then you don't even have to do template hackage just to get a simple `.size()` out of the container.

Comment: How is it called that property in C that is using the first parameter on the second one (size)?

Comment: Yes, things stop being terrible if you lower your standards. That's how the Universe works.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Let's not start this again. C++ is still not superior to C. C++ programmers are not smarter than C programmers. Neither is it true the other way around. No need for that kind of language war.

Comment: I didn't try to draw a distinction where there is none.

Comment: "C++ is not a superset of C anymore." was it ever?