# What are those strange array sizes [*] and [static] in C99?

Tags: c, arrays, c99, function-prototypes, c11

Apparently the following function prototypes are valid in C99 and C11:

```
void foo(int a[const *]);

void bar(int a[static volatile 10]);
```

What is the purpose of those strange subscript notations `*`, `static`, and CV qualifiers?

Do they help distinguish statically typed arrays from variable-length arrays? Or are they just syntactic sugar?

Comment: static: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430315/purpose-of-static-keyword-in-array-parameter-of-function

Comment: asterisk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371645/parameter-of-a-function

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**static in parameter array declarator**

```
 void f(int a[static 10]);
```

`static` here is an indication that parameter `a` is a pointer to `int` but that the array objet (where `a` is a pointer to its first element) has at least `10` elements.

A compiler has then the right to assume `f` argument is not `NULL` and therefore it could perform some optimizations. `gcc` currently performs no optimization ([source](http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html)):

> "The information provided by static in parameter array declarators is not used for optimization. It might make sense to use it in future in conjunction with work  on prefetching."

**qualifier in parameter array declarator**

```
void g(int a[cvr 10]);
```

inside `g` `a` is a *cvr* pointer to `int` (*cvr* is `const`, `volatile` or `restrict` qualifier). For example, with `const` it means `a` is a `const` pointer to `int` (i.e., type `int * const`).

So a parameter declaration:

```
T param[cvr e]
```

is the same as a parameter declaration:

```
T * cvr param
```

*****  **in parameter array declarator**

```
void h(int a[*]);
```

The `[*]` in a formal array parameter declaration in a function declaration (that is not part of a function definition) indicates that the formal array is a variable length array.

Comment: How is this useful? I don't seem to get *any* meaningful diagnostics when I call the functions with the wrong type of array (wrong size or wrong VLAness). Do you get `sizeof` support for `[*]`?

Comment: @KerrekSB C does not require the diagnostic and I guess compilers are not giving a warning because this feature is so rarely used.

Comment: @KerrekSB for `sizeof` with `int (*)[*]` for example with `gcc` I get *‘[\*]’ not allowed in other than function prototype scope*

Comment: @KerrekSB, `sizeof` for the `[*]` is not possible for the simple reason that this is **only** allowed in declarations and not in definitions. For VLA as function parameters the size expression is evaluated as if it where placed at the beginning of the function body. `[*]` is a placeholder for the expression in the declaration for those case where one doesn't know (or doesn't want) to make that expression visible in the interface. Inside the function `sizeof` works as expected, only that you don't have the first dimension, as always for array parameters.