# const for array size expressions on argument

Tags: c, arguments, constants

I have the following C code example:

```
int f(const int farg[const 5])
{
}
```

What does the additional const for the array size do? And what is the difference when I omit the const there?

Comment: [Possibly related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17559631/596781)

Comment: the second `const` gave me 4 compiler errors

Comment: @mch make sure your compiler supports C99 or C11. (-std=c11 for example). clang 3.4 with -std=c11 eats this up without issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
int d(const int darg[5])
```

Means `darg` is a pointer to `const` `int`.

```
int e(int earg[const 5])
```

Means `earg` is a `const` pointer to `int`.  This is a c99 feature. `T A[qualifier-list e]` is equivalent as `T * qualifier-list A` in the parameter declaration.

And of course (from above):

```
int f(const int farg[const 5])
```

Means `farg` is a `const` pointer to `const` `int`.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the additional const for the array size do?

**C11: 6.7.6.3:**

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to **‘‘qualified pointer to *type*’’**, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation.

This means

```
int f(const int farg[const 5])
```

will be adjusted to

```
int f(const int *const farg)
```

> And what is the difference when I omit the const there?

After omitting, it is equivalent to

```
int f(const int frag[5])  //or int f(const int frag[])
```

which is ultimately equivalent to

```
int f(const int *farg)
```

Comment: `const int farg[const 5]` is adjusted to `const int * const farg` not to `const int const *farg`.

Comment: @ouah; Oopa!. That was a typo. It should be `‘‘qualified pointer to type’’`