# Passing a variable length 2D array to a function

Tags: c, arrays, function

If I dynamically allocate a 2D array(malloc it),

```
int r,c;
scanf("%d%d",&r,&c);
int **arr = (int **)malloc(r * sizeof(int *));

for (i=0; i<r; i++)
     arr[i] = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));
```

and then later on pass it to a function whose prototype is:

```
fun(int **arr,int r,int c)
```

There is no issue. But when I declare a 2D array like VLA i.e.

```
int r,c;
scanf("%d%d",&r,&c);
int arr2[r][c];
```

It gives me an error when I try to pass it to the same function. Why is it so?
Is there any way by which we can pass the 2nd 2D array(arr2) to a function?

*I Know there are lots of similar questions but I didn't find one which address the same issue.*

Comment: I removed the C++ tag because VLAs arent' standard C++.

Comment: ok. I tried the code in c++. It was not working. Probably it won't work in c either.

Comment: You were looking for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225358/prototype-for-variable-length-arrays)

Answer (score 7):

A 1D array decays to a pointer. However, a 2D array does not decay to a pointer to a pointer.

When you have

```
int arr2[r][c];
```

and you want to use it to call a function, the function needs to be declared as:

```
void fun(int r, int c, int arr[][c]);
```

and call it with

```
fun(r, c, arr2);
```

Comment: probably you are saying arr is of type int** but arr2 is of type int *[c], right?

Comment: `arr`, the argument in `fun`, is of type `int (*)[c]`, not `int**`.